# On Mobile mode, I want the navigation popup menu be closed after selecting a link element, such as "Skills", "Contacts", etc

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, tailwind-css, navbar, web-frontend

Through this link, you can see a navigation menu bar popped up on a mobile device.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOw0Y.png

I just want it dissappear when you select a specific link which directs you to different sections on the website. I use React JS and Tailwind CSS for development.